# More efficient way to populate unordered_set?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, unordered-set

I have an array of integers stored contiguously in memory and I want to add them all to a `unordered_set` collection.

Right now, I am adding them one at a time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    collection.insert(pi[i]);
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

I realize that the items are not stored contiguously within the collection, so it won't be as simply as just handing the array over to the collection. But can this be optimized somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unordered_set` has a constructor that takes a range of elements to initially add them:

```
template< class InputIt >
unordered_set( InputIt first, InputIt last,
           size_type bucket_count = /*implementation-defined*/,
           const Hash& hash = Hash(),
           const key_equal& equal = key_equal(),
           const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you can just do `collection = std::unordered_set{ p, p + count };` and leave it up to implementation.

As other user pointed out in comments, there's also an overload for `insert` that takes a range:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

So, just like calling the constructor, you can do, `collection.insert(p, p + count);`

There's no guarantee that this overloads will be more efficient, since the complexity is linear in both overloads on average, as well as for just inserting elements one by one.

In fact, if we look into how `insert` is implemented in MSVC, it's very simple

```
template<class _Iter>
void insert(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
{   // insert [_First, _Last) at front, then put in place
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        emplace(*_First);
}
```

so no optimization for this case.

I think, the best way to go about this is to call `reserve`, if you know a number of elements you are going to add and, if there are many collisions (which there won't be for integers), maybe modifying `bucket_count`.

Comment: Is there any evidence that these alternatives are more efficient?  If so, what is the evidence, and what criteria?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: I get the impression that the implementation is up to the implementer. However, either of these approaches would allow your code to benefit from optimizations made in future versions of this class.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Obviously, they are more efficient in terms of amount of code needed to be written...

Comment: Fair point about evidence, as I've pointed out in my answer. `insert` can't even know how many elements you are adding since iterators are just `InputIt` and not random access.

Comment: @Aconcagua: True, and they may be a reason to use them. But by efficient, I meant at run time.

Comment: I've added my thoughts about efficiency at runtime. I think `reserve` and `bucket_count` are your only reasonable controls about how efficient adding elements will be.

Comment: @JonathanWood Was rather meant as humoristically... *Possibly*, the function call *inside* the loop (with single element insert) *might* be moved out of with the iterator variant, but if there's a profit at all depends entirely on implementation (single element variant inlined or not, further function calls in iterator variant or not)...

Comment: @egor the fact it requires input it does not peclude implementations for testing for random access, and optimizing that case.  I have "distance at least" helper functions to make this easy for me; when passed a range, I calculate 0 or the distance if they are random access iterators, and pre-researve space in bunch of internal library code.

Answer (score 3):

Using the range based constructor or the insert method will be concise and elegant but likely just as efficient as your method.
The reason is that the iterators passed to these functions are **input iterators** and not **random iterators**.
Because of that, the length of the range cannot be calculated and the elements must be inserted one by one with periodic rehashes when the load factor of the set gets to high.

Consider calling the [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve) method of std::unordered_set.

```cpp
collection.reserve(pi.size());
collection.insert(pi.begin(), pi.end());
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, one could also worry about the efficiency of hashing the inserted elements one by one.
It would then be efficient to be able to perform some sort of bulk insertions.
However, in the case of the OP, the elements are integers which happen to be hashed using the identity function in most if not all implementations of std::hash, which does not cost that much ;). Indeed, it is the best hash function one can get for random integers. Other hash functions might be more suitable in case of "organized" sets.

EDIT2:
The comment section is now speculating on what could be a better implementation of the insert method.
I maintain that the insert overload based on a range asks for input iterators, so yes, you can actually pass any non-output-iterator.
Also have a look at the worst case complexity for range insertion: you will see that it is specified so that it is allowed to insert elements one by one.
Finally, take a look at some implementations of the insert method and you will see that there is no particular overload for random access iterators.
This makes sens as there is no reason to impose an additional check in the insert method while the reserve method is here for the case where we want to set the container to, at least, a given capacity. 
Based on that, the answer above is very likely to be the best technique based on actual implementations of the stdlib.

Comment: Apart from the re-allocation problem, there's yet another (possibly more relevant) reason we cannot get more efficient: Each element needs to be hashed *independently* from the others, there's no way to profit from whatever relationship of the elements to be inserted (such that one could e. g. spare some hash calculations or insert groups of elements in junks).

Comment: @Aconcagua, What can you do about that ? If using std::unordered_set is required, then I can't think of a better way to insert a given number of elements.

Comment: Nothing. And that's my point... Imagine you could calculate hash for first element and use another (half as costly) algorithm profiting from previous hash for subsequent elements. *Then* iterator variant could get more efficient. Such stuff does not exist, thus we cannot be more efficient. In my eyes, it's the more important reason, but it's lacking in the answer (again in my eyes not worth a downvote, though – and I didn't...).

Comment: *The reason is that the iterators passed to these functions are **input iterators** and not **random iterators**.* ==> I would actually say that the constructor taking a range **requires** (at least) *input iterators*.

Comment: You can still pass *random-access iterators* to that constructor since these iterators also fulfil the requirements of *input iterators* (i.e., a random-access iterator is also an input iterator). Note that the iterators provided by an array are random-access iterators. Therefore, if random-access iterators are passed instead of strict input iterators, a particular implementation may be able to take advantage of this by calculating the number of elements that are going to be inserted and by accordingly reserving the space needed to avoid multiple rehashings.

Comment: (Elaborating on @ElProfesor comment) In C++ templates are transparent: the type argument is fully available. Even in C++ with concepts (which aren't even a proper meta type system). If a type supporting many operations is used in template that doesn't required such a "richer" type, there operations are available for that type, even if the template is expected to work w/o these. The code can use them when available. This is unlike O'Caml module instanciation which erases any operation not listed. This makes template more powerful but also more macro-like than cleaner O'Caml.